# VBA Send bulk emails performance concern

Tags: excel, vba, performance, outlook

I have the below macro which will scan an excel file with manager emails down Col B. For each manager, an email will be drafted/an excel file attached/ and sent automatically. I have been able to test this and it is working fine when drafting 50 - 100.

My concern is, **50 - 100** emails does not seem like a good indicator of knowing if this will work fine when sending **5,000** emails.

**Am I at risk of this freezing or other issues when running this on actual file with 5,000 emails?**

```
Sub CorpCard()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup

For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "urdearboy@hi.com"
            .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Your Employees With A Corporate Credit Card - EID - " & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value
                .Body = "Hi " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & "," _

                'Body to be patsed here

            strLocation = "C:\Users\urdearboy\Desktop\File Name " & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & ".xlsx"
            .Attachments.Add (strLocation)
        .Send
        End With

        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Would it be a good idea to house my `For Each` loop inside another loop something like `For i = 1 to 5000 Step 50` and then add `Do Events` before starting the actual loop to give my computer some time to catch up before proceeding with the next 50 emails? I'm not exactly sure if this is in the scope of `Do Events` though. I can also provide computer specs if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine for larger files. With that number of emails to send though, your run time could easily be over an hour. A good idea might be to raise some flag in the error handler in case it does encounter an issue. Maybe something like:

```
    if Err then
         Msgbox "Error Encountered at Row " & cell.row
    end if
```

right underneath the with-block.

Comment: I believe you mean `cell.row` but good idea! One hour run time is expected and **A-okay** for a task this size. So you don't think continuously spamming the outlook outbox with new emails will cause the program to freeze? That is my only concern.

Comment: Good catch on the cell.row! I've updated my response to fix that. I don't think so, no. I've been doing something very similar albeit more in the order of 1-2,000 emails and haven't had an issue beyond run-time.